# How to reorder file using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file as following format

```
Item-abc,c1,300
Item-abc,c2,500
Item-pqr,c1,900
Item-pqr,c2,800
Item-pqr,c3,600
Item-pqr,c4,700
Item-xyz,c1,950
Item-asd,
Item-jkl
```

I need this file rearranged in following manner

```
Item-abc,c1=300,c2=500
Item-pqr,c1=900,c2=800,c3=600,c4=700
Item-xyz,c1=950
```

```
If second and third columns are empty then that line should ve removed completely
```

Comment: Is input sorted?

Comment: sorting is not concerned

Comment: It certainly matters if the input is sorted.  If it's not, the simpler solution sorts it first.  If it is already sorted, that is wasted work.

Comment: Input is not sorted in any order (asc or desc) but the first column value of entire records in the file appear grouped together

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
$1 != prev { if (NR>2) print rec; rec=prev=$1 }
{ rec = rec OFS $2 "=" $3 }
END { print rec }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Item-abc,c1=300,c2=500
Item-pqr,c1=900,c2=800,c3=600
```

Comment: Item-abc,c1,300
Item-xyz,c2,950
Item-pqr,c3,900
Item-pqr,c4,901

Shows like :-

Item-xyz,c2=950
,c4=901r,c3=900

Comment: The script I posted produces the expected output you posted from the sample input you posted. If you have a case that the script doesn't work for then include that case in your question, not in a comment where it's unreadable.

Comment: I see you removed the header line from your updated sample input - that would certainly break things of course. Add it back or change `NR>2` to `NR>1` in my solution.

Comment: My Input :
Item-abc,c1,300<br>

Item-pqr,c1,900<br>

Item-pqr,c2,901<br>

Item-xyz,c1,950<br>

My Output :

Item-abc,c1=300<br>

,c2=901r,c1=900<br>

Item-xyz,c1=950<br>

Note : Header Line removed

Expected output :

Item-abc,c1=300 <br>

Item-pqr,c1=900,c2=901 <br>

Item-xyz,c1=950 <br>

Comment: First column value can be repeated any number of times. Set of Second Column values  will be unique for a particular first column value. Same First column value appears together

Comment: Again - If you have a case that the script doesn't work for then include that case in your question, not in a comment where it's unreadable.

Comment: If there carriage return (\r) or new line character(\n) in file at the end, this solution will fail. Please change the code which accommodate my concern also.

Comment: Last time - If you have a case that the script doesn't work for then include that case in your question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
 cat answer.awk
    BEGIN {
    FS=","
    RS="\r\n"  # For Windows"
    }

    {
        N[$1,$2]= $3
    }

    END {
        for (comb in N) {
           split (comb,S,SUBSEP)
           K[S[1]]=K[S[1]] "," S[2] "=" N[S[1],S[2]]
        }
        for (j in K) if (j != "Name") print j  K[j]
    }

    awk -f answer.awk file
    Item-abc,c1=300,c2=500
    Item-pqr,c1=900,c2=800,c3=600
```

Comment: Item-abc,c1,300
Item-pqr,c1,900
Item-pqr,c2,901
Item-xyz,c1,950


Shows Error like as follows (header line excluded and tried)


Item-abc,c1=300
,c2=901r,c1=900
Item-xyz,c1=950

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you tried the code above on input file:   Item-abc,c1,300   Item-pqr,c1,900   <br/>Item-pqr,c2,901   <br/>Item-xyz,c1,950  <br/> and got some problems?   <br/>I tried it on my side and got following result:   <br/>Item-abc,c1=300   <br/>Item-pqr,c1=900,c2=901   <br/>Item-xyz,c1=950   <br/>Is it what expected? (looks like site does not permit line breaks :( )

Comment: Jenin, sorry, do not follow you.... input and output does not contain header line...

Comment: My Input :
Item-abc,c1,300<br>

Item-pqr,c1,900<br>

Item-pqr,c2,901<br>

Item-xyz,c1,950<br>

My Output :

Item-abc,c1=300<br>

,c2=901r,c1=900<br>

Item-xyz,c1=950<br>

Note : Header Line removed

Expected output :

Item-abc,c1=300 <br>

Item-pqr,c1=900,c2=901 <br>

Item-xyz,c1=950 <br>

Comment: First column value can be repeated any number of times. Set of Second Column values  will be unique for a particular first column value. Same First column value appears together

Comment: ... have no idea why on your side you get different result from me.  I can not reproduce it. On my side I get same result as your expected.

Comment: Just tried Ed's version, it also works fine on my side.

Comment: As an option you can use Ed's version, but looks like it assumes that input file is sorted by 1-st column, otherwise result will be different.

Comment: Mine doesn't assume the input is sorted, just that it's grouped by the first field like the OP said it is in their comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776857/how-to-reorder-file-using-awk/57777406?noredirect=1#comment101989367_57776857 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776857/how-to-reorder-file-using-awk/57777406?noredirect=1#comment102019928_57777648

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, sorry, right, it assumes not sorting but grouping.

Comment: @JerinJ, if both my and Ed's code return same result, but which differs from what we get on our side, then it make sense to look thoroughly into your input files, probably they differ from what you shown to us....

Comment: If there carriage return (\r) or new line character(\n) in file at the end, this solution will fail. Please change the code which accommodate my concern also.

Comment: Jerin, please clarify, which line separator is used in you files. Is it Linux like \n or is  it Windows \r\n. You can specify it in BEGIN {} section.
For Linux RS="\n" for Windows RS="\r\n"

Answer (score 0):

@Jerin, this variant will strip \r'ss

```
BEGIN {
FS=","
}

{
    sub(/\x0d/,"",$0)
    split($0,Cols)
    N[Cols[1],Cols[2]]= Cols[3]
}

END {
    for (comb in N) {
       split (comb,S,SUBSEP)
       K[S[1]]=K[S[1]] "," S[2] "=" N[S[1],S[2]]
    }
    for (j in K) if (j != "Name") print j  K[j]
}
```